# Jquery Mobile: size attribute for select tag

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is it possible to use the "size" attribute in a  with Jquery Mobile ?
I can't seem to make it work.

```
<select id = "chosenmodel" size="4" data-theme="b" data-native-menu="false">
</select>
```

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @AdamJosephLooze I am trying to display a scrollable list where elements can be selected. Actually I already have a <select> but I would like it to display 4 lines and I would like to be able to scroll to next lines.